# Scrolling is jittery in IE, Safari, OSX

Tags: javascript, css, macos, internet-explorer, safari

I'm trying to do some basic parallax animation, but the movement is extremely jittery as soon as I test in IE or any OSX browser - not sure why!

http://willmurdoch.com/scrolltest/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.hero').each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() > -$(window).height() && $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(window).height()){
      var myTranslate =  Math.ceil($(window).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top);
      $(this).find('.heroSlides').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY('+myTranslate/2+'px)');
      $(this).find('.scrollWrap').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY('+myTranslate/5+'px)');
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried locking scroll functions to only fire every 100ms and transition in between, adding hardware acceleration to every animated element, but nothing seems to do it! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i think showing more of your code would help. Like where is the scroll event listener?

Comment: I added the rest too, it was just a wrapper for the scroll function itself and a loop checking for each element I want to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that I've found that adds smoothness to my CSS transformations, is to add the CSS Transformations

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Another thing you can do is look at [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and how that project works.  It does math based easing for its smooth scrolling.

## EDIT

On the page you posted, try changing the following functions:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  scrollLogic();
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  closeNav();
});
```

change to:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  //scrollLogic();
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  closeNav();
});

var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
  scrollLogic();
}, 1000/30);
```

Then change the `myTranslate` part of `scrollLogic`.  Play with different values to make the change more/less gradual.

Comment: This didn't 100% fix it, but it helped tremendously, I'm satisfied with how it's working now! Thanks so much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason to use 1000/30 as the timer, instead of something smaller or just 33?

Comment: I use 1000/30 because that's easier to read.  I know that is 30 FPS.  It's also easy to change to 1000/60 if you want 60 FPS. just personal preference!